# 3.3 -> 4.1 migration fails, busted RAMCache AttributeError: 'RAMCache' object has no attribute '_cacheId'

Tags: plone

After 3.3 -> 4.1 migration I get exception on the resulting page

```
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.viewletmanager-2.0.2-py2.6.egg/plone/app/viewletmanager/manager.py", line 85, in render
        return u'\n'.join([viewlet.render() for viewlet in self.viewlets])
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.memoize-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/plone/memoize/volatile.py", line 281, in replacement
        cached_value = cache.get(key, _marker)
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.memoize-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/plone/memoize/ram.py", line 124, in get
        return self.__getitem__(key)
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.memoize-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/plone/memoize/ram.py", line 166, in __getitem__
        MARKER)
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.ramcache-1.0-py2.6.egg/zope/ramcache/ram.py", line 107, in query
        s = self._getStorage()
      File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.ramcache-1.0-py2.6.egg/zope/ramcache/ram.py", line 122, in _getStorage
        cacheId = self._cacheId
    AttributeError: 'RAMCache' object has no attribute '_cacheId'
```

Looks like RAMCache object is in invalid state.

Also before this seeing in logs:

```
  2012-06-21 16:42:54 INFO plone.app.upgrade Ran upgrade step: Miscellaneous
  2012-06-21 16:42:54 INFO plone.app.upgrade End of upgrade path, migration has finished
  2012-06-21 16:42:54 INFO plone.app.upgrade Your Plone instance is now up-to-date.
  2012-06-21 16:43:02 ERROR txn.4553572352 Error in tpc_abort() on manager <Connection at 10be48490>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/transaction-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/transaction/_transaction.py", line 484, in _cleanup
      rm.tpc_abort(self)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZODB/Connection.py", line 730, in tpc_abort
      self._storage.tpc_abort(transaction)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZEO/ClientStorage.py", line 1157, in tpc_abort
      self._server.tpc_abort(id(txn))
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZEO/ServerStub.py", line 255, in tpc_abort
      self.rpc.call('tpc_abort', id)
    File "/fast/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.6-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/ZEO/zrpc/connection.py", line 768, in call
      raise inst # error raised by server
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fast/xxx-2012/var/blobstorage/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x07/0xdc/0x55/0x00FWigqp.tmp-'
  2012-06-21 16:43:03 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1340286183.10.000607291180815 http://localhost:9666/xxx/@@plone-upgrade
  Traceback (innermost last):
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 134, in publish
    Module Zope2.App.startup, line 301, in commit
    Module transaction._manager, line 89, in commit
    Module transaction._transaction, line 329, in commit
    Module transaction._transaction, line 446, in _commitResources
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 781, in tpc_vote
    Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 1098, in tpc_vote
    Module ZEO.ClientStorage, line 929, in _check_serials
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fast/xxx-2012/var/blobstorage/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x00/0x07/0xdd/0xca/0x009kWNYQ.tmp-'
```

- Why this would might happen?
- Any pointers how to reinitialize RAMCache object?

RAMCache is first time referred by FaviconViewlet which is using @memoize deorator and it leads to this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your migration obviously did not complete successfully, based on the traceback. So I would focus on figuring out why it failed, rather than working around things like the broken RAMCache which are likely a result of the migration not having run.

The traceback indicates that it broke while trying to *abort* the transaction...so you'll probably need to do some debugging to determine what caused it to *try* to abort, since that's not indicated in the logs you pasted.

Comment: Thanks. This put me to the right track. It was not entirely sure what went wrong, but the page shown after the migration caused an exception - it somehow tried to render viewlets, but failed there. This exception did not leave much of trace in the logs. The solution was switching old 3.3. Data.fs to "Plone Default Theme" before running the migration.